# Issues with MongoDB Connector for Solr

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am trying to use the MongoDB connector with MongoDB and Solr for search purposes. I know MongoDB is working properly. I also have Solr up and running. I have added the LukeRequestHandler to the solrconfig.xml file. The issue I am having is when I run the command to start the MongoDB Connector I receive the following error:
pysolr.SolrError: [Reason: /solr/admin/luke]
Any help would e greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py
2014-06-22 09:16:10,404 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
2014-06-22 09:16:10,461 - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
2014-06-22 09:16:10,464 - INFO - Finished 
'http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/luke?show=schema&wt=json' (get) with body '' in 0.010 seconds.
2014-06-22 09:16:10,468 - ERROR - [Reason: /solr/admin/luke]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/mongo-connector", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('mongo-connector==1.2.1-', 'console_scripts', 'mongo-connector')()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector-1.2.1_-py2.6.egg/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 720, in main
continue_on_error=options.continue_on_error
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector-1.2.1_-py2.6.egg/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 154, in __init__
**docman_kwargs))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py", line 57, in __init__
 self._build_fields()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py", line 71, in _build_fields
declared_fields = self.solr._send_request('get', ADMIN_URL)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 321, in _send_request
raise SolrError(error_message)
pysolr.SolrError: [Reason: /solr/admin/luke]
```

Comment: plz, specify stacktrace

Comment: pysolr creates the error message in SolrError from content scraped from the server's response. You'll probably get more context for the error by visiting http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/luke?show=schema&wt=json in a browser. Could you update your question with what you see there?